# iDevice crashes due to animated sprite

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation, sprite

I'm trying to have one of my sprites have an animation when my hero hits it, my app crashes on my iDevice and xCode seems to blame it on the animated SKAction that I made.

This is my code:

```
var fire: SKSpriteNode! = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"1")//I've set this as a universal variable

var anime = SKAction.animateWithTextures([SKTexture(imageNamed: "1"), // apparently this line causes the crash
        SKTexture(imageNamed:"2"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed:"3"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed:"4"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed:"5"),
        SKTexture(imageNamed:"6"),//this line is also a problem apparently
        SKTexture(imageNamed:"7")], timePerFrame: 0.1)
    fire.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(anime))
    fire.size = CGSize(width: targetSprite.size.width*1.3, height: self.frame.size.height*0.9)
    fire.position = targetSprite.position
    fire.runAction(SKAction.sequence([fall,kill]))
    addChild(fire)
return fire
```

after the crash xCode points to one of the two lines I've pointed out and says EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 and it has no crash message.

Comment: Your iOS device actually crashes or do you mean that your app crashes? Huge difference. Assuming you mean the app crashes, update your question with relevant details about the crash. Point out the exact line of code causing the crash.

Comment: my iOS device crashes, on the simulator it works perfectly fine and I'll point out the line that causes the crash.

Comment: Really? Your iPhone or iPad actually crashes and reboots?

Comment: no it crashes and goes to the home screen, it doesn't reboot

Comment: So your app crashes, not the iOS device. HUGE difference. As I said in my first comment, in this case, update your question with details about the app crash. There should be a stack trace and an error message.

Comment: oops sorry about that :) I fixed it